# Depositing an insurance check made out to a foreign ltd into a personal US account

Tags: united-states, banking, insurance, international

I own a boat which is registered in the BVI's in an Ltd. name. There is no business and thus no bank account for it. I am a U.S. citizen with a regular U.S. bank account. I incurred boat damage and am getting a check from my boat insurer for repairs, but the insurer will only make the check out to the foreign Ltd. in which name the boat is titled. Is there any way to deposit the check into my account? It is my boat, and I am the one who pays the premiums for it. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Why was it registered in a Ltd. name in the first place?

Comment: After much thought I decided it would be safer to have a non US flag because of where I take her. Sad to say.